# Twitter Bootstrap accordion feature

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Working with Bootstrap and JavaScript and I am using it as an accordion format - once  clicked on the collapsed `div` it will open and show the items within the `div` based on the id.

**Problem:**

If the `div` doesn't contain any items i want it to open and show a message to the user:

```
"no items here"
```

How do I go about doing that? In the JavaScript ?

This is what I have:

**View**

```
<div class="accordion-body collapse state-loading" data-group-id="13" data-bind="attr: { 'id': 'GroupMember_' + Id(), 'data-type-id': ModelId() }" id="GroupMember_15" data-type-id="15">
      <div class="accordion-inner no_border" data-bind="foreach: Children"></div><!--END: accordion-inner--></div>
</div>
```

If the `Children` are `0` i want it to open and have this text show: `No items here`

**Javascript:**

```
OnSuccess: function (data) {
                var _groups = linq.From(options.groupData);    
                var _groupsToUpdate = _groups .Where(function (x) { return x.Id == options.groupId; });
                if (_groupsToUpdate.Any()) {
                    _groupsToUpdate.First().Children = data.Items;                  
                }
```

Not sure if i am missing anything else to share - let me know.

**UPDATE**

Div Layout:

```
<div class='accordion-group'>
     <div class='accordion-heading'> Group 1 </div>
     <div class='accordion-body'>
          <div class='accordion-inner'> 
              <div class='element'>No items here</div> 
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

I have to click on the 'accordion-heading' class in order to display the 'accordion-body' and get into the `accordion-inner` items

Comment: how are you adding content to the accordion in the first place ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to bind to the `show` event on the accordion elements and perform your check there, from your classes I'm assuming your using Bootstrap v2.3.2:

```
$('.accordion .collapse').on('show', function () {
    var $inner = $(this).find('.accordion-inner');
    if($inner.is(':empty')){
        $inner.html('No items here');
    }   
});
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gttw8/)**

Note that the `:empty` selector is very picky, it will not work if there's any white space between the opening and closing tags of `.accordion-inner`.

You may also use `if(!$.trim($inner.html()))` to check if the element is empty or as @JL suggested check the length of the children elements just beware that text nodes are not treated like children, so a div with only text would be considered empty

Comment: This is what i am looking for thanks! but i am trying and i am having some trouble i think the structure of how i have my `div`s are affecting it. I will update my post to show the structure of how i have the info and maybe you can help to structure the js to suit what i have

Comment: @Masriyah can you provide a fiddle with the complete accordion code?

Comment: @Masriyah my solution works perfectly out of the box http://jsfiddle.net/Gttw8/23/

Comment: it's working great in jsfiddle but when i copy the same js into my script tag and run the page it is not showing anything at all - i am frustrated somewhat thinking that i am missing something in view

Comment: @Masriyah are you wrapping the code inside your `$(document).ready(function(){...})` ?

Comment: yes  i do. I am starting to think that maybe something is interfering with knockout javascript that i have to load the elements and that i should do the checking within there.

Comment: @Masriyah I'm not familiar with knockout but it seems that you could easily perform the check in the success function you posted, just check the length of `data.Items` and set the content accordingly. As to why the code is not working, is the accordion structure present on page load or are you adding the elements dynamically? I mean the headings, body, etc. not the inner content, also I noticed the code in your fiddle doesn't match the markup you posted at the beginning of your question under "View", so can you confirm that your code actually looks like the one in the fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Do you have jQuery installed? You can check if a `<div>` has children like this:

```
if ($('#divId').children().length == 0) {
     $('#divId').append("no items here");
}
```

If you don't have jQuery:

```
if (!document.getElementById('divId').hasChildNodes()) {
    document.getElementById('divId').innerHTML = "no items here";
}
```

Based on your edit, I think we're inspecting `accordian-inner` for children. If so, give it an ID and substitute that into our code. Note: You don't need a `<div>` to contain our "no items" message...the message will get printed with javascript (Plus, if you have a `<div>` there, then you've in effect added a child and the message no longer applies). Change your HTML to this:

```
<div class='accordion-group'>
     <div class='accordion-heading'> Group 1 </div>
     <div class='accordion-body'>
          <div id='innerId' class='accordion-inner'> 
              <!-- Remove the 'element' div -->
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Then:

```
if (!document.getElementById('innerId').hasChildNodes()) {
    document.getElementById('innerId').innerHTML = "no items here";
}
```

Comment: i am trying this but i think i have my div structure differently and it might not be working because of it. I updated my post to the structure i have - if you can take a look and share feedback. Thanks

Comment: could i add this `if` statement into my javascript?

Comment: @Masriyah Yes, on page load