# adding text to empty div with twitter bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

This is relating to my previous question [Twitter Bootstrap accordion feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305441/twitter-bootstrap-accordion-feature)

i wanted to know the `.find()` works - does it look for a class of a div in a specified scope or does it look for it on  the whole page?

```
$('.accordion-heading').on('click', function () {
            var $inner = $(this).find('.accordion-inner no_border');
            if (!$.trim($inner.html())) {
                $inner.html('No items');
            }
        });
```

in the above code - i have to click on the link in the accordion-heading so i could open the accordion-body(not in accordion-heading div) which contains the accordion-inner. if the div elements in the accordion-inner div empty - then it should add text to the elements div "no items"

Javascript in page: This is how i have the javascript added to view page so i can see how the script is working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $.views.AllItems.Init();
        });

        $('.accordion-heading').on('click', function () {
        var inner = $(this).siblings('.accordion-body').find('.accordion-inner .element');

        if ($.trim(inner.html()).length == 0) {
            inner.html('No items');
        }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: I suggest wrapping your code in `$(document).ready(function() { code here });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have the HTML look like this:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
              Group Item #1
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                <div class="element">blach blah blah</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">
                Group Item #2
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
            <div class="accordion-inner"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in order to target the div with class "accordion-inner" you'll have to use `.siblings('.accordion-inner')`, since `.find()` looks for descendants.

`.siblings()` gets the siblings of an element (elements in the same level).

Update: Forgot you need to do a `.find()` once you've found the sibling.

Thus the example would be:

```
$('.accordion-heading').on('click', function () {
    var inner = $(this).siblings('.accordion-body').find('.accordion-inner');

    if ($.trim(inner.html()).length == 0) {
        inner.html('No items');
    }
});
```

Thus your javascript should be included like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(function () {
            $.views.AllItems.Init();
        });

        $('.accordion-heading').on('click', function () {
            var inner = $(this).siblings('.accordion-body').find('.accordion-inner');

            if ($.trim(inner.html()).length == 0) {
                inner.html('No items');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This seems perfectly right but i am not sure why it is not working :( i have this piece of js in the view page to test

Comment: I updated my post to include how i added the javascript to the page in a script tag

Comment: @Masriyah I changed the code a bit. Didn't take the .element div into calculations, and I forgot to remove $ in front of the inner in the if-statement. Above code should work.

Comment: Is there a way i could debug in the console to see if it is hitting this script? i am still not seeing what i need to be seeing

Comment: Depends on your browser. But most modern browsers support using `console.log()`

Comment: Yes, `console.log()` also works for Firefox, you just need to open the Web Developer Tools :)

Comment: here is a quick demo in jsfiddle and this is what i am getting: http://jsfiddle.net/Gttw8/16/

Comment: @Masriyah updated the post to reflect how it should look with that HTML. The `.element` should not be included since you don't have an element with class element within the accordion-inner. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery `find` will search for descendants contained within the given jquery, in this case `$(this)` is a JQuery object that contains 1 element - the one `.accordion-heading` that was clicked on. Thus the element matched would be one that would be also matched by css selector

```
.accordion-heading .accordion-inner no_border
```

Of course this does not work as it searches for a `<no_border></no_border>` element inside an element with `accordion-inner` class. Maybe you mean `.no_border`

Answer (score 0):

it will works for all `.accordion-inner no_border` inside the `according-heading.`

```
$(this).find('.accordion-inner','.no_border');
```